# CSS class ID questions

Tags: html, css, class

Quick question about CSS -  Do all Divs need an id or some sort of identifier? For example on my html page I have the code shown below (by reusing classes I can create a structure / fluid grid system).

The page does validate without issues..

```
<div id="wrapper" >

    <div class="section group"> // open section 

        <div class="col span2"> 
            *****CONTENT HERE *******
        </div>

        <div class="col span2"> 
            ********MORE CONTENT HERE********** 
        </div>

    </div> // close section

</div> close wrapper
```

- Section holds columns. (It gives the div 100% width and clear both). It is used to divide the page up
- group is a class that applies Clearfix
- col is a column that is floated left (holds  content)
- span is a class that gives col its % dimensions for fluid design (Eg span 1 = 25% width span 2 = 50% width, span 3 = 75% span 4 = 100%)

Answer (score 2):

First of all I can see in your example code maybe some missing close tags, but I say maybe because I am not sure if you did forgot to paste a part of the code. Anyways, any open div should have its close div.

And to answer your question:

No, html elements do not need to have id attribute defined.

Some of the purposes of id attribute are to identify unique elements. The same id must not be repeated. Then you can use the id from CSS by specifying the id selector prefixed by `#` as you did with your wrapper.

The id can be used either to be able to specify that unique element's style by css or to work with it from javascript by using `document.getElementById('id-here')` or `jQuery $('#id-here')` .

The main difference from using classes vs ids in CSS is that a ID is unique but a CLASS can be used more times on more than one element.

When you write your CSS style you should:

1. First apply style to html tags by avoiding to use classes if not required, for example: `p { color:red; } h1 { color: black; }`
2. Second, if your paragraphs really need a class, you should create it: `p.italic {font-style:italic}`
3. Third, if you've got a paragraph with unique design on the page, you can use: `p#unique_id { font-size:300%; }`

What I'm trying to say is that you should use it as required, don't add classes if you don't need them, add ids for unique items.

Comment: well you could just use them so that the content has a container, for example <div>some text here</div> instead of just leaving the text in the air, and as skobaljic said in his answer, you could have for example.. <div class="some-class"><h1>title</h1><div>text</div></div>, you could then do div.some-class h1 { color: red; } and div.some-class div { color: blue; } so you have a div that has no class but you can still apply style to it

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need all the classes. If you want to reduce the code, you can address them in css as:

```
/* For .section and clearfix (.group) */
#wrapper > div {}
/* For .col */
#wrapper > div > div {}
```

That way your html becomes:

```
<div id="wrapper" >
    <!-- BEGIN section -->  
    <div>
        <!-- BEGIN column --> 
        <div> 
            *****CONTENT HERE *******
        </div>
        <!-- END column --> 
    </div>
    <!-- END section --> 
    <!-- BEGIN section -->  
    <div>
        <!-- BEGIN column --> 
        <div> 
            *****CONTENT HERE *******
        </div>
        <!-- END column --> 
    </div>
    <!-- END section --> 
</div><!-- /#wrapper -->
```